# how to add the provisioning profile into the bundle ID list

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I can't find the provisioning profile in the bundle ID list when i tried to send my application into the iTunes connect.

[image]

how can i add the provisioning profile, i used in the archive, into the list of the Bundle ID so that i pick it when submitting the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't look for the provisioning profile in the Bundle ID list, you should be looking for the App ID (com.yourCompany.yourApp) you created for your app in the Provisioning Portal. Your provisioning profiles are created after you create your App ID and they're values correspond to the App ID you selected when making them.

Comment: Ok, but the App ID `com.mycompanyname.myappname` i already created doesn't figure in the list when i try to configure the application form in iTunes. Please how can i add it to that list described in the picture above? thanx

Comment: Have you previously created a new app in iTunes Connect using that App ID?

Comment: Yes actually, is that why i didn't get it in the list?

Comment: That is exactly why. Hope this helped you!